# is it possible to run GUI based app through driver after a particular event - call_usermodehelper not working ???

Tags: user-interface, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

In our target board I have to call a GUI application through driver after a particular interrupt occurrence automatically , after surfing through internet I found "call_usermodehelper". But while testing it with Firefox it returns success status but Firefox is not started ( poweroff like stuff working well ), so what's  happening there and why it can execute poweroff binary but not Firefox ? is there any other way to execute our own GUI based application through driver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any other way to execute our own GUI based application
>   through driver ?

You can poll proc entry from userspace script, and if state is changed run your GUI application.